# The function filter have to modify the list a by removing all items a[i] such that b[i] is False

Tags: python, list

For example if :

```
a=[1,2,4]
b=[True,False,False]
```

The function filter must return:

```
a=[1]
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. See also: [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you meant to achieve?

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
b=[True,True,False,False,True,False,True]
idx = [i for i in range(len(b)) if b[i]]
print([a[i] for i in idx])
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 5, 7]
```

If you are looking for a one-liner: `[a[i] for i in [j for j in range(len(b)) if b[j]]]`

Answer (score 0):

One option

```
a=[1,2,4]
b=[True,True,False]
new_list = []
for index,value in enumerate((a)):
    if b[index]:
        new_list.append(value)
new_list
```

Same thing but, list comprehension

```
[v for i,v in enumerate(a) if b[i]]
```

Comment: Your solution is neater! `[v for i,v in enumerate(a) if b[i]]`